# Approximating an Integral using series

Tags: calculus

Approximate the integral to 4 decimal places.
$$ \large \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-1}^{1}e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}=0.68$$
All I have figured out is $$ \large  e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}} =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2^n n!}$$
Therefore we have 
$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-1}^{1}e^{- \frac{x^2}{2}}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{-1}^{1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)2^n n!}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}[\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)2^n n!}]_{-1}^{1}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\left (\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)2^n n!}-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{3n+1}}{(2n+1)2^n n!}  \right)$$
I have computed the first 9 terms and my error was .002. 
As n becomes larger the terms are soo small and the sequence converges soo slowly.

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

Then an antiderivative for $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ will have a series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)2^nn!}.
$$
Use this to evaluate the integral.

Comment: Have not seen this method in my calc book.

Comment: Is there any other method?

Comment: This is the standard method.  The series gives you an antiderivative.  Presumably you will only need the first few terms to get the digit accuracy you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you simplify your integral by noting that it is an even function.

$$ \int_{-1}^{1} e^{-x^2 /2} = 2\int_0^{1} e^{-x^2/2}$$

Comment: Ohhh yaaa. Lemme see if I have an easier time now :)